# SlidingMenu jfeinstein - can't instantiate activity

Tags: android

I set my MainActivity`s contentview on this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slidingmenu);
    setUpActionBar();
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
sliding:viewAbove="@layout/activity_main"
sliding:viewBehind="@layout/activity_left"
sliding:touchModeAbove="fullscreen"
sliding:fadeEnabled="true"
sliding:selectorEnabled="false"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main and activity_left are normal views, but I get an error:

```
05-31 16:46:33.407: E/AndroidRuntime(23698): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.multamedio.teaserapp/de.multamedio.teaserapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: You have problem in your sliding menu code

Comment: where is it? Can you tell me where?

Comment: You should swap to the [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) added in support-v4 ver13.

Comment: the library is not working anymore with new versions?

Comment: To be clear, Google recently announced their own Navigation Drawer, which is included in the Support Library.  I don't think there is enough detail in the log included.   It looks like you might have an error in the layout file you are including inside the Sliding Menu.  (XML tags not matched, or something like that)